# Brightness controls are not working in sony vaio with amd radeon hd 7650

Tags: 12.10, brightness, radeon, vaio

I have a Sony Vaio SVE15116EN with AMD Radeon HD 7650 graphics card. I am currently using Ubuntu 12.10. My brightness controls are not working but sound controls are working fine. I have also tried proprietary drivers also but no luck. I have tried controlling brightness with terminal but it also did not work. Please can anyone tell me what can i do? I have been searching for the solution almost for a week. Any ideas?

Comment: The below link helped me, now I am able to adjust my brightness
http://superuser.com/questions/400417/brightness-settings-gone-how-do-i-bring-it-back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Download the amd radeon driver from [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)
2. Run terminal and tupe`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic`
3. Go to directory where you have downloaded the zip file of driver which might be /home/your_username/Downloads. Extract the zip file there. You will see a .run file.
4. Run command: `sudo sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run`
5. It will open the installer window. Now install the driver. After finishing it will ask you to reboot but don't.
6. Open a new terminal and type: `sudo amdconfig --initial`
7. Now reboot your system. Your brightness control will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you use radeon graphics this may help you

```
echo 200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

Comment: This works like a charm on Toshiba Satellite L750D-A269 with Radeon 7400M and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a yet better way to do this with GUI based installation method, worked well for my card ati card 7650 on sony vaio
http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-ati-amd-catalyst-drivers-in.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: GUI based installation method is also good. But the command line method also works when you get the low graphics error on Ubuntu start-up and you won't be able to use GUI at all. But you can do ctrl-alt-F1 and use the command line method to solve the low graphics problem.