# Unable to change Screen Brightness on Toshiba Laptop Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, brightness, toshiba-satellite

I have a Toshiba Satellite C655D-S5209 with Ubuntu 12.04. I am unable to change the screen brightness. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> move the brightness indicator, but actual brightness does not change.

I have tried several fixes but none have worked so far:

Updated Bios to newest version and updated graphics driver to latest version.

Tried editing grub about 100 times to include several suggested acpi options - none helped

Tried installing `acpi` and `acpitools` - didn't work so removed.

Tried installing `fnfx` and `fnfx-client` - didn't work so removed.

Tried editing `xorg.conf` - might have done something wrong with this because it broke my system, and had to use recovery mode.

The screen hurts my eyes. Either need a fix, some window tinting to put on my screen, or to reinstall Windows.

Comment: What graphics card + driver does it have?

Comment: 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310]

Comment: ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver VESA:WRESTLER

Comment: Had the same issue. Installing the fglrx driver from ubuntu repo didn't hel either. But downloading and installing the latest AMD drivers from their website fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Try installing display drivers:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/247145/brightness-controls-are-not-working-in-sony-vaio-with-amd-radeon-hd-7650

Comment: The solution described here, worked on my Toshiba:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/374677/full-brightness-and-keyboard-backligh-at-boot

Answer (score 0):

Just boot into an older kernel, probably 3.5.0-19, if you have it. It solved the exactly same problem on my satellite L850.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script I used at some time to change my brightness when I needed a temporary fix.

`#! /bin/bash
echo -n "Select brightness (0.1 - 1): "
read -e BRIGHTNESS
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness $BRIGHTNESS
echo Brightness has been set to $BRIGHTNESS 
sleep 0.5`

You can open up a terminal and run `xrandr`, in the second line it should say something like "VGA1" or "LVDS1 connected" replace VGA1 from the script with whatever value xrandr returns.

Save it as brightness.sh (remember to make it executable) and run from terminal or assign to key (Keyboard Shortcuts are in System->Preferences).

This could be easily modified to increase and decrease brightness with different keys.

Comment: I had to change "--output VGA1" to the output my system was actually using. You can find it out by running xrandr on a terminal.