# Full brightness and keyboard backligh at boot

Tags: grub2, 13.10, keyboard, screen, brightness

I own an Asus N56VZ, and each time I start Ubuntu (13.10 and prior versions) my screen brightness and keyboard backlights reset their values to the max. Ubuntu doesn't save my settings on reboot. I was wondering if someone could help me with this? It is horrible when, at night, I turn on my computer - it is like looking directly to the sun, and it hurts my eyes. I tried googling and none of the pages I found actually helped.

I think my issue might be grub-related. I have a dual-boot with Windows 8.1, so before I start my computer I see grub to choose my operating system. My screen starts at full brightness as soon as I reach grub. Maybe he is making the OS forget about my last values, overriding it with its?

Does someone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance :)

PS: I'm using bumblebee with Nvidia driver 304, but this issue existed before I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the grub configuration file.

In a terminal type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the line where there is `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Then type `sudo update-grub` in the terminal and reboot to test.

This worked for me on a previous computer.

Comment: I already did that (first result on Google)... It results at full brightness and the fn shortcuts stop working.. No good for me :/