# Only can move the pointer after upgrading

Tags: unity, graphics

I made a partition on my desktop pc, 100 GB and installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it. It was pretty slow first thought it had to install updates or something, so I rebooted it. Now after the login it looks like everything freezes, I can move my mouse only, but that's it! I can see my desktop and launcher, but the task bar doesn't display time and misc system info, only a black bar, I downloaded the Android SDK pack and installed vlc media player before I rebooted.

My computer info:

- 1 TB HDD
- 8 GB ddr3 RAM
- ATI Radeon 4890 videocard (1 GB)
- AMD Phenom 2 x4 black 3, 2ghz CPU (64 bits)

Comment: Have you installed drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: No I didn't. I already uninstalled the OS. I salvaged my dad's old pc its HDD and placed it inside my computer. Installed Ubuntu 12.10 x64 from cd onto the 'new' HDD (160gb). Installation went flawless, but after the installation I had to log in and the same thing happened; I can't do anything...

Comment: Try to use GNOME classic (gnome-shell), this could be a video driver issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments. Can I do this during/before my login? And how can I download a videocard driver through this OS?

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk` to install a program called 'additional drivers', use this to install drivers.

Answer (score 4):

## Note: If you can boot into Ubuntu just fine, skip to step 8.

If this is a video card issue following these steps should fix the problem (make sure you have internet):

1. Boot as far into Ubuntu as you can
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a terminal.
3. Log in with you username and passoword
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`
5. Then

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
   ```

   (this one will take a while)  Note: you might be asked which display manager you want to use, select 'lightdm'
6. After all that is finished run `sudo reboot now` which will reboot your computer
7. At the login screen, click on the ubuntu logo, in the top right corner of the window, and select "GNOME Classic" click OK, and login.

**8.** After you have logged into Gnome Classic, open 'Software Center' [image]
9. Click 'Edit' from the menu and select 'Software Sources'
11. Open the 'Additional Drivers' tab[image]
12. Select the driver you want and click 'Apply Changes'
13. Reboot.

`Jockey-gtk` has been integrated into software sources inside the software center.

So in 12.10 you change drivers by:

1. Opening software center
2. Clicking 'Edit' --> 'Software Sources'
3. Opening the 'Additional Drivers' tab
4. Selecting the driver you want and clicking 'Apply Changes'

If the above steps don't fix the problem, then your graphics card is probably not supported.

In this case you have four options:

1. You can install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (where I think your graphics card is still supported)
2. You can continue to use Gnome Classic
3. You can use [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) by running `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` or installing from scratch.
4. Or you can try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) by running `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` or installing from scratch.

Kubuntu is also worth mentioning, but I'm not sure it will work without drivers.  You can try though.  `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Wow, thank you. I can't find the 'additional driver's program in the software centre (installed). If I download it through Firefox it says it has already been installed.

Comment: Oh, sorry `jockey-gtk` has been removed from 12.10.  For the time being try `jockey-kde`

Comment: Thank you for your time and great explanation iSeth. It is weird, I installed the jockey-kde , but it doesn't show any drivers. Look at this: http://i.imgur.com/5lKJU.jpg [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/5lKJU.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Can you post more info about your machine? e.g. Make and Model? I'm afraid your graphics card is not supported in 12.10.  It _should_ work on 12.04 though. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu/74172#74172) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Comment: I use the radeon HD 4850 1gb videocard

Comment: Oh, the 4850 or the 4890? You said 4890 earlier. This could change everything.

Comment: I grabbed my documentation, it is the 4890 HD indeed, sorry

Comment: Thats ok, could you tell me the model of your computer?

Comment: I don't have a branded computer, I assembled the parts. I have a list of all my hardware though:  1TB SAT2 WD10EADS/CLUB1gb D5 X HD4890/SonyNEC 24x SA LS 7241S BLB/Card Reader 68in1 int. Blck U2/CooMas Centurion 5 Silver ATX/Tt Thoughpower 14cm CM 750W ATX2/GiBy MA790XT-UD4P 790X F RGSA/AMD X4 II955 AM3 3200 Black 8M/Scythe Kabuto SCKBT-1000/D3 4GB 1333-777(2x)