# ubuntu install black screen - nomodeset not working

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I just bought ASUS UX42VS and I am have troubles installing ubuntu 12.10. After booting from USB or CD, whatever I select in the grub menu, the screen goes black and the computer does nothing. I have already tried to edit grub settings with `nospalsh noguiet nomodeset` but it did not help. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to copy answer from another question, because I think it applies here.  You can view the original question/answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/222433/44179)

If this is a video card issue following these steps should fix the problem (make sure you have internet):

1. Boot as far into Ubuntu as you can
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a terminal.
3. Log in with you username and passoword
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`
5. Then `sudo apt-get install gnome-core` (this one will take a while)  Note: you might be asked which display manager you want to use, select 'lightdm'
6. After all that is finished run `sudo reboot now` which will reboot your computer
7. At the login screen, click on the ubuntu logo, in the top right corner of the window, and select "GNOME Classic" click OK, and login.
8. After you have logged into Gnome Classic, open 'Software Center' [image]
9. Click 'Edit' from the menu and select 'Software Sources'
10. Open the 'Additional Drivers' tab[image]
11. Select the driver you want and click 'Apply Changes'
12. Reboot.

***EDIT:*** `Jockey-gtk` has been integrated into software sources inside the software center.

So in 12.10 you change drivers by:

1. Opening software center
2. Clicking 'Edit' --> 'Software Sources'
3. Opening the 'Additional Drivers' tab
4. Selecting the driver you want and clicking 'Apply Changes'

I edited the directions to reflect this.

***EDIT***

If the above steps don't fix the probelem, then your graphics card is probably not supported.

In this case you have four options:

1. You can install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (where I think your graphics card is still supported)
2. You can continue to use Gnome Classic
3. You can use [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) by running `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` or installing from scratch.
4. Or you can try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) by running `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` or installing from scratch.

Kubuntu is also worth mentioning, but I'm not sure it will work without drivers.  You can try though.  `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the scope of my problems is even larger. You see I can't even get ubuntu live CD started. So the advice to log as far into ubuntu as I can is useless for me... The computer is completely new so I have only win 8 installed. I do the following: 1. boot from installation media 2. select try ubuntu without installing or install ubuntu 3. edit the option by pressing e and change it to nosplash noquiet nomodeset 4. pressing f10 5. and the screen goes immediately black a the computer halts and does absolutely nothing. Please help! I hate windows and win 8 even more! Thx