# NVIDIA GT630M and Intel HD 4000 issues

Tags: nvidia, graphics, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I have a Lenovo Z580 (12.10 Quantal). It has both an Intel HD 4000 and an NVIDIA GT 630M (CUDA and Optimus).

When using Ubuntu, my laptop battery runs out much quicker than on Windows and the laptop also heats up more than on Windows. Is that because Ubuntu is using the NVIDIA card all the time?

I don't have any driver installed for the card. I tried `apt-get install nvidia-current` to get the proper driver but it caused many problems. (Resolution stuck on 640 x 480, taskbar and launcher not appearing, only background shows, i used ctrl + alt +t to open a terminal and remove nvidia current)

Do I need to install proper drivers (or Bumblebee)? Will it help my battery life?

Comment: You should see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/222433/44179) answer on installing drivers.  If there isn't anything in the list, your card probably isn't supported.

Comment: You said running `apt-get install nvidia-curretn` "cause many problems." Please edit your question to include detailed information about the problems it caused. For example, if there were error messages when you ran it, please let us know exactly what they said (you can run it again to get them). If it installed but the drivers did not work properly, please explain what you saw that made you know they didn't work right. This information may be valuable in enabling us to provide an answer, since it lets us narrow down what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First install nvidia drivers and then reboot it.

Open terminal and then make changes to /etc/X11/xorg.conf file to adjust HorizSync and VertRefresh under Section "Monitor" to achieve desired screen resolution.

For better battery backup, I would recommend you to install Jupiter package from Software center. Then optimize the configurations in it.

try checking your cpu temperature with the command "acpi -t" before and after installing the Jupiter package.

You will feel it much better now.