# Unity really slow on Radeon 6950

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, graphics, performance

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I need to do/if my system should be able to run Ubuntu 12.10 smoothly.

- Asus sabertooth x58,
- i7 3.2Ghz,
- 12 GB 1600 DDR3,
- x2 HD Radeon 6950 2GB,
- 2TB 7200rpm HDD,
- 850W PSU

I'm pretty sure it should be able to run the OS smoothly.. even if its the most resource intensive. But its performing poorly in fact its probably performing worse than my satellite pro c660 but then I haven't actually tested. I’ve downloaded and switched to the classic gnome desktop so that it'll run smoothly (Tried the fancy Gnome but due to duel screens it made go really weird)

So anyone any suggestions on how to increase system performance? If not can anyone suggest any 'pretty' GUI setup that supports duel screens and has a dock?

Many Thanks

Comment: I need a little clarification.  It doesn't run smoothly in the default Unity, correct?  And so you switched to Gnome Classic and now it does?

Comment: You would be correct (: sorry for being unclear! When using default Unity it doesn't run well at all, very slow loading apps, the search applications is slow etc, right clicking desktop is laggy. Gnome Classic all is well smooth

Comment: Have you installed drivers for your graphics card?  If not check out these other questions: [What ATI cards are supported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu), [Installing ATI drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/222433/44179) one explains installing drivers via the GUI.

Comment: A quote from the hardware support site:  "Radeon HD 6950/6970  (requires Catalyst 11.4b; open-source requires kernel 2.6.39)"

Comment: I had just been using the default ubuntu ones - I've just changed them to the propitiatory ones found under Additional Drivers in the Software sources... is that what you meant for me to try?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your quote means? Sorry you are talking to a complete Linux noob here!

Comment: Yes, try changing the drivers.  The propitiatory drivers usually work best.

Comment: tried changing them via the software centre, seems to have made things worse? They wont display full screen either now? Unity won't even load up and i've had it crash and reboot on me :/

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/124292/44179)?

Comment: was just about to (: ^^ just thought I’d let you know how that went

Comment: Okay so I tried that method, I'm back to full screen! But Unity is still super laggy.. is this just a fault with unity/my graphics cards not compatible?

Comment: I don't know.  It seems like alot of other people have bad graphics with this card.

Comment: Its not a bad card, i mean i can play Skyrim modded to hell and back on it 2048/4096 textures everywhere etc... hmm thanks for your help! I'll just suck it up and use Gnome whilst i browse through other GUI setups! Anyways it all good fun!

Comment: It not the card.  It has to do with driver issues.  Its a good idea to try out other desktop environments as most will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problem is with your graphics driver for your graphic card, try installing suitable drivers for your card, your cpu is good, so check with your graphic drivers. Check this link for more detail : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Another option is to use LXDE desktop environment rather than unity and gnome classic