# Graphical glitches

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

So I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 from the Windows installer (dual-boot). Ubuntu seems to boot fine until it gets to the login screen. There are small graphical glitches in the screen and whenever I move the mouse, it becomes even worse (I can barely see anything on the screen). I run it on a mini-laptop with AMD Athlon 64 processor and ATI Radeon graphics. It seems to be a problem with my drivers, but I am really new to Ubuntu and Linux and I can't find how to solve my problem (I know very little about the terminal since I used cygwin for SSH communications with a server). It is not connected to internet (I have a wifi, but I can't get Ubuntu to connect to it).

Comment: You might want to check out [this] (http://askubuntu.com/a/222433/44179) post and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/44179) post.  They might help you.

Comment: UPDATE: Considering they have pretty much [killed Wubi now](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/036993.html) I recommend getting Ubuntu on a [DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or a [USB Stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and trying out the 'LiveCD' version on them (for the most recent 13.04).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing until I installed the 13.2 beta drivers.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Comment: thanks,but how do I install it since I can't use the graphic inteface? Can I simply install it from Windows?

Comment: I followed this guide http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29_BETA.2FEXPERIMENTAL