# How to reduce brightness for sony vaio with 7650 HD

Tags: ati, graphics, brightness, vaio

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a Sony Vaio laptop. The brightness functions keys don't change the brightness. When I try to change the brightness I can see the levels going up and down in the notification bubble but it doesn't actually change the brightness. Is there any way to fix this?

i tried this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23907/changing-brightness-on-a-sony-vaio-laptop/290403#290403) but it didn't work.

Moreover i have installed additional amd drivers and i am using xorg drivers

Answer (score 0):

you have to concentrate on top right corner of your Ubuntu main screen, there will be one screen brightness adjustment option u will see.Then go through that option and make your own desired brightness.